# Accessing HttpSession outside of the originally receiving thread

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, httpsession

I'm using Spring 3. When controller gets requests it passes control to method `someMethod()` annotated with `@Async` in Service bean and then returns. When I access in `someMethod()` HttpSession object I receive this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you 
referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or 
processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are 
actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your 
code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In 
this case, use RequestContextListener or 
RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HttpSession` object itself can be used in multiple threads (but is **not** thread-safe and therefore must be synchronized). However Spring is doing some extra magic e.g. when you have `session`-scoped beans. Namely it uses `ThreadLocal` underneath to bind current session with thread.

I don't know what is your exact scenario, but apparently Spring tries to retrieve `HttpSession` from this `ThreadLocal` while you are in another thread - which obviously fails.

The solution is simple - extract session attributes you need in `@Async` method and pass them directly. This is by the way much better design - avoid passing `HttpSession` object around because it makes testing harder and your code is much less likely to be reused in the future.

Comment: Your solution is simple and good but then where can I store user specific data if I need them not only in controller layer but also in business and data layers? Or I have to pass these data through method arguments? Is the latter the only solution?

Comment: @OleksandrBondarenko: Think about it - by accessing the session in your service layer you are introducing hidden coupling and non-explicit dependency. Passing all this data via arguments (possibly by wrapping it in some object) is really the best option.

Comment: But what about SETTING things on the session? Do you have any documentation to back up your assertion that you can access HttpSession outside of a request?